# will Task Scheduler support in Windows 8.1 store apps using c#?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, scheduled-tasks

I just want to know whether we can call the Task Scheduler in C# for Windows 8.1 Store           Apps.Because when I call the task scheduler in windows store project using itaskservice it raises an com api exception that is not supported.if it not supported means any other alternative solution is there? kindly guide me

Comment: I need to know why I'm getting the negatve reputation

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it. Store Apps are quite heavily sandboxed, and can't perform system changes like that.

WPF is the appropriate choice here.